# caching the old image

Tags: php, caching

I have this ajax upload avatar, where you crop your image too before you press "Use". When you press use, at the userbar at the top, your current avatar disappears and your new avatar appears(made with jquery).

Now I have a issue here, that after you have uploaded the image, crop and pressed use, and after it changed with jquery, when i navigate to e.g Settings, home or profile, my old avatar comes back on. Until i press on my browsers "update" it shows the new one.

Although this happens only sometimes, sometimes i dont need to update.. how can i solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you upload the avatar, you can delete the old one and give a new file name to the new avatar. Then on the userbar and other places, link to the new one. This will definitely resolve your issue, but might take a little while for you need a little change in code (especially if your site is live).

Or you can keep track of a version number. Each time the user upload a new avatar, increment this version number. Then link the avatar to:

```
http://example.com/images/USERNAME.jpg?v=VERSION_NUMBER
```

Comment: You wrote this answer just before I was about to press enter after my answer lol.

Comment: On the first option, yes, I would like to remain the filename as I wouldnt think it would be any good to make new filename each time, when its only an avatar. I would like to know more about the increment version number, what should i do more exactly? Should i store the version number in the db too or? thanks

Comment: @Karam yep you can probably store it in the database as another integer. then each time you want to show the avatar, just append the version number at the back of the image URL like I've shown you in the answer.